# How would I make a try and expect block python to catch an infinite loop in a for loop

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working on a problem where I have to output the smallest number bigger than N consisting of the same digits as N. If there is no such number, I must print "0" as the output. This is the code I have for now...

```
n = int(input())
copy = n+1
while True:
    if sorted(str(n)) == sorted(str(copy)):
        print(copy)
        break
    else:
        copy+=1
```

I can not find a way to catch if a number has no such numbers, so, therefore, "0." I was thinking a try expect block but it somehow catches infinite loops. Any idea of how to implement this, or any other suggestions? Thank you!

SAMPLE INPUT/OUTPUT

input 1: `156`

output 1: `165`

input 2: `330`

output 2: `0` (No such number fulfills the condition)

input 3: `27711`

output 3: `71127`

Comment: Can you put a sample input and output?

Comment: If `len(str(copy)) > len(str(n))`, there's no longer any possibility of them having the same digits, because they no longer have the same number of digits.

Comment: sure! Edited @HarshalParekh

Comment: @jasonharper but they have to consist of the same digits, that would only check for there length

Comment: If `n` was a 3-digit number, and `copy` had counted up to 1000 without finding a solution with rearranged digits, then my point is that *you're done* - no further values of `copy` have any possibility to be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have a different approach to the problem:

1. If all digits sorted in descending order, then output is always -1. For example, 321.
2. For other cases, we need to process the number from rightmost side (why? because we need to find the smallest of all greater numbers)

---

### Algorithm

1. Traverse the given number from rightmost digit, keep traversing till you find a digit which is smaller than the previously traversed digit. For example, if the input number is “534976”, we stop at 4 because 4 is smaller than next digit 9. If we do not find such a digit, then output is “Not Possible”.
2. Now search the right side of above found digit ‘d’ for the smallest digit greater than ‘d’. For “534976″, the right side of 4 contains “976”. The smallest digit greater than 4 is 6.
3. Swap the above found two digits, we get 536974 in above example.
4. Now sort all digits from position next to ‘d’ to the end of number. The number that we get after sorting is the output. Finally, for above example, We get “536479” which is the next greater number for input 534976.
5. In last step we should check weather the result is a 32-bit number or not.

---

### Code

```py
def nextGreaterElement(n):
    n = list(str(n))
    N = len(n)

    for x in range(N - 1, 0, -1):
        if n[x] > n[x - 1]:
            i = x - 1
            break
    else:
        return -1

    swap = i + 1
    pos = i

    for x in range(swap, N):
        if n[pos] < n[x] < n[swap]:
            swap = x

    n[pos], n[swap] = n[swap], n[pos]

    ans = int(''.join(n[:pos + 1]) + ''.join(sorted(n[pos + 1:])))

    return ans if len(bin(ans)[2:]) < 32 else -1    


print(nextGreaterElement(123))
# 132
```